# Abrupt increase in RMSE in LSTM while working on Time Series Prediction

Tags: keras, deep-learning, neural-network, artificial-intelligence, lstm

I have the following LSTM network(Fig 1) for predicting the Bitcoin Price. The input is every hour close price of Bitcoin. I am facing some issues and any advice is appreciated.

1. Earlier on the same network, my RMSE on testing and training set was 6.71 and 7.41 RMSE. I recompiled the whole code and there was an abrupt increase to 233.51 for the training set and 345.56 for the testing set. Can anyone help me with finding out the reason behind this?
2. Also, How to improve the accuracy of my network as it very low in every iteration?
3. How should I decide the parameters for my LSTM network. (units, epochs, batch_size, time_steps to input)

Thank you in advance for any help extended.

[image: Fig 1]

Comment: accuracy is not a metric for regression tasks

Comment: Okay. Thanks for confirming it. Also, is there a way to reduce the RMSE ?

Answer (score 0):

Your question requires a lot more information. For example, data size, timesteps lookback, data preprocessing procedure, etc. But I would recommend you to debug your problem with the following method. First, check whether your input/output data are processed properly or not. Then, try to train the simpler model apart from LSTM as it could result in overfitting. But sometimes, if the input signal is too random, it is normal that your model results would highly fluctuate as there's no correlation in data.

PS. never use the Machine Learning model to predict stock price. It never works.

Comment: I have data of shape (43845,1), timesteps lookback is 24*2, I have implemented the MinMaxScaler to scale the closing value between 0 and 1.

Comment: Also, what would you recommend other than Machine learning to predict the prices?